# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.>Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details

Tags: android-studio, firebase, build.gradle

```
apply plugin:'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.tubbs.citychurchob"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
buildTypes{
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir:'libs', include:['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
}
```

How to fix this error 
Pls ans me..... 
I'm using Android studio 2.3.1

Comment: What does the compiler error output show?  Also, your post shows `buildToolsVersion "25.3.1"`.  The latest version of build tools I can find is 25.0.2.  Is 25.3.1 really what you are using?

Comment: Sorry  typing mistake.. sorry  here my codes